# StyleInterval with cut in column

Tags: r, dt

I recently started exploring DT and I am stuck on something. Imagine the following table:

```
dt <- data.table(group = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3),
                 group2 = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
                 interval = c(NA, NA, 100, NA, NA, 150, NA, NA, 100),
                 value1 = c(1000, 10, 90, 2000, 30, 120, 1500, 25, 150), 
                 value2 = c(1200, 10, 110, 2500, 35, 145, 2200, 40, 90))
```

Now I want to create a DT with a Style that checks the value in value1 and value2 and compares it with the value in Interval. I tried something like this:

```
datatable(dt) %>% formatStyle(
    columns = c("value1", "value2"),
    backgroundColor = styleInterval(interval, c("red", "green"))
)
```

But interval is not recognized as an object. This leads me to believe that I cannot pass a column in the cut parameter. I also tried to pass some kind of function in the valueColumns but this didn't seem to be possible either.

Expected output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense to pass the full column to *styleInterval*. It requires **n** values for *cut* and **n+1** for *values*. Try alternative below instead:

```
myCut <- sort(unique(dt$interval))
myCol <- rainbow(length(myCut) + 1)

formatStyle(datatable(dt),
  columns = c("value1", "value2"),
  backgroundColor = styleInterval(myCut, myCol))
```

[image]

Comment: I understand where you are going with this but the cuts should be dependent on the interval in that specific row. I will add an expected output to my original question to avoid confusion

Comment: @WietsedeVries Thought so, too. I think styleInterval is not the right function to use in this case. Just wanted to illustrate the issue.

Comment: I see what you mean. Right now I create a hidden column for each value column that calculates the value-interval. This works but the code is quite messy especially because I need to account for a variable amount of value columns

Comment: @WietsedeVries I'd go with hidden columns, too. Can't see DT doing this rowwise without diving into JS.